# ASP.NET MVC5 C# - error occurred connection to SQL Server. server not found/ not accessible

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I am learning ASP.NET MVC5 and as such I need to access some database in order to get the data, since I am using the Code First method. As I was following some tutorial online, they used "update-database" in Visual Studio and connected to the DB. however, when I tried, I got this error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.

Most of the people who posted here were discussing VS 2012 or before, so this is for VS 2015 when trying to access the database.

Answer (score 3):

If you are getting this error it could be for a range of reasons. The one that I faced was that there was a problem connecting to the database. 
If you are facing the same issue, this is the way that i fixed it:

1) go to the Microsoft SQL Server Express 2014 downloads page - or [click here for direct link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver2014express.aspx).
2)Assuming that this is your first time downloading SQL Server, then scroll down the page until you come to

> Installation for new users:
>
> Download Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Express

3) click it and you will be asked to sign into your .live account.
4) after signing in, you will be taken to the next page
5) here, select :

> SQL Server 2014 LocalDB Express 32bit
>   OR
>   SQL Server 2014 LocalDB Express 64bit

6)depending on where you are a 32bit machine or 64bit machine, select the appropriate one, the language you want etc. (fill out the details)
7)click continue and in the downloads bar you will see

> SqlLocalDB.msi

8)once this is downloaded, go ahead and run the installer
9)once the installation is complete, you now want to go back to VS Community 2015, or 2014, whichever one you have.

10) now, you need to do two things once you have your project loaded up
10.1) go to web.config (this is the very last file in solutions explorer, I DO NOT MEAN THE ONE INSIDE VIEWS)
10.2) between the `<connectionStrings> </connectionStrings>` do you have this? :

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" 
     connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDb;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-BOB-20160604094017.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-BOB-20160604094017;Integrated Security=True" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

10.3) if so, then great, we can move onto the next stage (ideally it will be there) - if not, then add that snippet to your  `<connectionStrings>`
HOWEVER make sure that you change "BOB" to your projectName, I believe the long digit can be kept the same
10.4) In the code snippet that i have posted, look for

> (LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDb;

does this exist in your code? if so then move onto the next step, otherwise change the snippet to make sure that you include this little snippet after "Datasource =

11) now that this has been done, go to Tools->Connect To Database
12) make sure your data source is Microsoft SQL Server
13) add the Server name:

> (LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDb;

(this is the same snippet as above, except this is what is checked for the connection)

14) click test connection
14.1) if successful, then you can click ok, and you are done!
14.2) if not, then go back and check all the steps to make sure everything has been done correctly and it should work!

Comment: sorry about the numbering, it went a bit funny when i was typing it..

Comment: nice detailed answer +1

Answer (score 0):

Mostly this is the error where your connection string is not valid and thus you should change it to something like this :

```
<connectionStrings> 
    <add name="Connection_Name" connectionString="Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=Db_Name;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />      
  </connectionStrings>
```